# TextWrangler always comes to front when switching monitors

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, bbedit

I have a late 2012 mac mini running OSX 10.9.3 and I'm curious if there is a setting that needs to be changed or if this is some sort of bug. I'm working with two monitors; one plugged into HDMI and the other using the display port with a VGA adapter.

Regardless of which application I am using on my VGA monitor, when I switch to the HDMI monitor by clicking into an application, TextWrangler comes to the front. I've searched through system settings and TextWrangler settings, but I couldn't find anything to fix this problem.

This is incredibly irritating and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If you quit TextWrangler does it work normally?

Comment: Yes, this problem seems to only happen with TextWrangler.

Comment: Well now that I've quit and re-opened the program, it stopped coming to the front. I don't know what could have caused it, but it's back to normal now.

Comment: So killing the application and re-opening did the trick? You should consider writing this as answer, maybe others have the same issue with an application popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quitting TextWrangler and re-opening it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command line tools where you open it with

```
edit yourfile.txt
```

Then there is a flag you can use to open it in the background. You can defualt this via an alias in your .bash_profile or .cshrc

The flag is:

```
edit -b
```

The .bash_profle alias would look like:

```
alias edit='edit -b'
```